# Does a UK/US dual citizen toddler need an ESTA to visit the US

Tags: usa, uk, esta, dual-nationality

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything that fits exactly.

I am a British citizen and my wife is a US citizen, we live in the UK and she has indefinite leave to remain. Our 3 year old son has a British passport.

I guess our son is dual citizen even though he doesn't have a US passport? Does he require a ESTA the same as me to visit the US?

Comment: No! He requires a US passport (8 USC 1185, travel control of citizens and aliens: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1185)  Anecdotal evidence suggests, though, that they will be a bit lenient with small children.  If he travels on his UK passport, though, he definitely *will* need an ESTA.

Comment: In case you decide to forego the US passport: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1199/~/children--do-children-require-esta%3F

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78768/us-citizen-entering-usa-as-non-citizen
The consensus there was that the child should travel on a US passport, but travelling on the UK passport should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he is registered with the US authorities as a US citizen, he Needs a US passport. Otherwise he'll Need an ESTA tied to his British passport

Comment: Registration has nothing to do with it.  The child either is or isn't a US citizen.  The only thing is that if the child hasn't yet had any contact with US authorities then they're more likely to get in with a minimum of fuss.  (On the other hand, if the child had a US passport and the parents didn't bring it for some reason, there would likely be considerably more fuss.)

Comment: @phoog "The child either is or isn't a US citizen". I know that, but in actual practice, when it comes to OP's travel, it's largely a matter of the US authorities knowing or not actually knowing about the child's US citizenship.

Comment: I figured you know that, but since in the UK "registration" has a more definite meaning, I wanted to mention it to avoid confusion.  If the family travel together, the border officers will (I suspect) be fairly likely to wonder whether the child is a US citizen, and, if he is, to figure that out.  They can question the mother to determine whether she was eligible to pass on her citizenship when the child was born.  They may admonish the parents that the child needs a US passport; I think that's the worst possible consequence.  The safest course of action is to get the child a US passport.

Comment: Indeed, it's as straightforward as applying for a Consular Report of Birth Abroad at the nearest US Embassy or Consulate where an officer approves the application, and the State Department issues a CRBA (Form FS-240) which is proof of US citizenship and is used to get a US passport.

Comment: @phoog - The child is eligible for US citizenship, but not required to become so.  If the parents have not filed a Report of Birth and the mother has not docmented her qualifications to pass citizenship to the child, then the child is solely a UK citizen.

Comment: @phoog This should be an answer

Comment: @Tom do you have any basis for that assertion?  US citizenship law operates automatically. Registration is not required. See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-child-born-abroad.html.  It would of course be possible for someone born abroad not to know that he is a USC, but if US authorities decide that he is, he'll be liable for taxes etc.  The absence of a CRBA only changes the likelihood that the person's US citizenship comes to the attention of US authorities; it doesn't change the fact of the person's US citizenship.

Comment: @phoog - as per my comment AND your link, the US citizen needs to document their qualifications to pass citizenship on to the child.  This qualification process is part of registering a foreign birth.  Not every US citizen can pass citizenship to their child.

Comment: @Tom the parent does not need to document anything to pass citizenship to the child. If the parent meets the residence criteria, the child is a US citizen.

Comment: @phoog - "meets the residence criteria" hence something to document.

Comment: @Tom something to document, perhaps, just as birth in US territory is something to document. But a lack of documentation does not deprive the child of US citizenship, and in no case can the child or the child's parents or anyone else choose whether the child becomes a US citizen. If the child is eligible for citizenship, the child is a citizen. There's no question of the child being required or not to become one. This is in contrast to certain people who are eligible to become British citizens by registration. In those cases, the person can choose.

Comment: @phoog - I bow to the almighty phoog.  Obviously everything the Embassy told me when I registered by daughter's birth was wrong.

Comment: @Tom This is interesting `"Not every US citizen can pass citizenship to their child."` In what circumstances would a US citizen not be able to pass it to their child?

Comment: @superphonic A US citizen who has never lived in the US, for example.

Comment: @supersonic A US citizen who has lived less than 5 years of their lives in the US.

Comment: @Tom I already asked if you had any basis for your assertion, and you did not mention anything about what the embassy told you.  What did they tell you?  Embassies are not always right, I might add.  A citizen born overseas might have an easier time of living as a non-citizen than a US-born citizen, but in the law he is still a US citizen, and an immigration officer or judge can make that determination in the absence of a CRBA.  I should find out if my uncle ever got a CRBA.

Comment: @Tom I thought of these comments a few days ago when a friend of mine told a story about her dual-citizen friend who was coming to the US for a wedding.  The embassy told him that if he traveled to the US without a US passport, he would lose his US citizenship, which is patently false.

Comment: @phoog Isn't it downright illegal for the embassy to lie about things like that? Saying that they're technically obliged to use a US passport is one Thing, but this? Wow!

Comment: @Crazydre there is a lot of misinformation in the US about these things, even among government employees.  I would attribute this to incompetence rather than mendacity, and I doubt very highly that it is illegal.

Comment: @phoog US citizens that give birth abroad are required to report to the US Consulate, before his/her 18th birthday. Should provide local certificate of birth and proof that at least one of the parents is a US citizen. That will ease any bureaucracy later to obtain a passport or travel to the USA. Specially true for _Birth Abroad Out-of-Wedlock to a U.S. Citizen Mother_ :
[Acquisition of U.S. Citizenship by a Child Born Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-child-born-abroad.html)

Comment: @phoog and regarding the _transmission of US citizenship_, read this:
[Transmitting Citizenship](https://ca.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/birth/transmit-citizenship/)

Comment: @roetnig "required"? No. After the US citizen's 18th birthday, it is no longer possible to get a CRBA, but the person is still a US citizen, and there is no penalty for failing to get a CRBA other than the additional bureaucratic burden of not having a CRBA.  See https://ca.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/citizenship-claims/.

Comment: @phoog. I was born in Spain, from British parent. I was registered in the consulate at birth. I didn't have any problem at all to obtain a British passport. My sister also was born in Spain, She was not registered in the consulate at birth. It was a real nightmare for her to obtain a British passport. Anyway... Read this:  [U.S. Citizenship](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship) and this: [Citizenship Through Parents](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-parents). As non registered there are more and more "ifs" to get his citizenship recognized.

Comment: @roetnig British laws and procedures don't have much bearing on US laws and procedures.  My point is only that failure to register at the consulate at birth doesn't mean that the child loses its claim to US citizenship.  Of course it will be easier to establish that claim with a CBRA, and easier to get the CBRA the sooner it is done after the child's birth.  It may well be a nightmare to establish the child's US citizenship after the 18th birthday.  But registration with the consulate before the 18th birthday is not "required" as you claimed.

Comment: @phoog Tell those who claim citizenship and have to supply Evidence of U.S. Citizenship of Parent(s), Certified copy of the Parents’ Marriage Certificate, Evidence of your parent’s/parents’ residence/physical presence in the United States, and to have an interview before a USCIS officer, who may be very ticky, that it wasn't required, and that a simple Birth Certificate would be enough to avoid the hassle. The most common documents that establish U.S. citizenship are: **Birth Certificate** (including CRBA), **US Passport**, **Certificate of Citizenship**, **Naturalization Certificate**.

Comment: The easiest to obtain is the CRBA, of course not "mandatory", but "required"

Comment: @roetnig my dictionary defines both "mandatory" and "required" as "compulsory."  They are synonyms.

Comment: No, they aren't. As I said, any of the previously mentioned document is required, but none is mandatory.

Comment: @roetnig how are they not synonyms?  What sense does one word have but the other lack?