# US citizen entering USA as non-citizen

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, uk-citizens, dual-nationality

The situation: Husband (UK citizen) and wife (US citizen) live together in the UK with their child, who was born in the UK and has never left that country. Child holds British passport. Per US law, the child is a US citizen (the mother meets the residence requirements outlined [here](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume12-PartH-Chapter3.html) and is automatically a citizen at birth) and is eligible for a US passport. However, the child's birth was never declared to the US authorities. From the point of view of the US, the child does not exist, and they do not know that the child is a citizen. The parents aren't interested in having the child be a US citizen or have a US passport, although technically the child *is* a US citizen.

The question: Can the child enter the US on a British passport (when travelling with both parents)?

My speculation: I know that US citizens must enter the US with their US passport (see e.g. [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-and-dual-nationality/dual-nationality.html)), but in this case, the child does not have a US passport and no-one knows that they are a citizen. So I suspect that the answer to my question is "no, it is a violation of the law for the child to enter the US on a British passport", but practically speaking, is this regulation enforced, especially for a child who (for all intents and purposes) does not exist?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm specifically asking about arriving in the US by air on a flight from the UK. Will the child be able to enter the US on their British passport, or will the border officials say "we suspect you are a US citizen" and levy a fine or some other punitive measure?

Comment: Very close to yesterday's question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78729/does-a-uk-us-dual-citizen-toddler-need-an-esta-to-visit-the-us

Comment: Not recognizing the child's US citizenship could have unpleasant consequences in the long term. For example, the child will be required, under US law, to file US tax returns. It may be simpler in the long term to get that US passport, raise the child in the knowledge of dual citizenship, and let the child decide at age 18 whether to renounce one of the citizenships.

Comment: @Dorothy thanks! I searched around but looks like I missed that question.

Comment: No problem and, as the comment there, getting a Consular Report of Birth Abroad is easy and solves/avoids current or future issues.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for the perspective. In this case, since no US authorities know that the child exists, is there potential for problems at customs & immigration?

Comment: @Dorothy Do you mean that with a Consular Report of Birth Abroad, the child can enter the US on a British Passport? Or is that just a document that will assist in getting the US passport?

Comment: Yes; the latter; see here at "Children" https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/74/~/us-citizens---documents-needed-for-entry-into-the-u.s.

Comment: Thanks, but that link is only for land/sea travel from the western hemisphere. I should have clarified in the original post that I'm specifically asking about air travel from the UK to US.

Comment: Suppose they try to have the child travel on a UK passport. What are they going to say on the child's ESTA application? I believe it asks whether the applicant is a citizen of any other country.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Good point. I don't think they have completed the ESTA application yet. Would declaring US citizenship cause an automatic refusal of the ESTA?

Comment: @throughaweigh US citizens are not supposed to be able to get ESTA authorization.  But, although I couldn't find it just now, there was at one point a page in which the US government suggested that dual citizens can use the VWP to travel without their US passports in an emergency.  That may have predated the time when the appilcation asked about dual citizenship.  There is no fine for a US citizen entering the US without a passport -- the statutory penalty was repealed in the 70s.  As I understand it, if they find you out, you'll get a lecture about needing to get a passport for your child.

Comment: Immigration will go like this: "Are you the child's mother?" "Yes." "And you are a US citizen, correct?" "Yes." "Is the child a US citizen?" "Err..." If you do decide to risk it, you had better have an answer ready to that last question.

Comment: @TonyK Excellent point! Forgive my ignorance, but then what happens? You say "yes", "no", or "I don't know" - what are the consequences? Is there a fine? Denial of entry? Phoog suggests it's (just?) a lecture from the agent. A note on your file for future agents?

Comment: I strongly recommend telling the truth. Suppose the parents lie. Will the child be expected to continue the lie, and if so, how long? What happens in 30 years time, if it would be very advantageous to be able to work in the USA, but there would be a decade of penalties for non-filing of tax returns?

Comment: I have seen, personally, an American-born child of Israeli emigrants to the USA pulled over at an Israeli border (exit, interestingly) and ordered to get an Israeli passport. He held Israeli citizenship, under Israeli law. If, like the US, the UK passport application includes mother's place of birth, and then that shows up on some US border agent's screen, urk. If the child later makes the sort of money that would be a tax problem, then he can give up the USA citizenship.

Comment: @TonyK: The answer could be "I don't know" or "maybe but I don't have the evidence to prove it right now". Transmission of citizenship to a child born abroad depends on many factors including past periods of physical presence of the parent in the US which may be difficult to remember or find evidence for.

Comment: @user102008: Yes, you are probably right. The OP wrote "Per US law, the child is a US citizen", and I took that at face value.

Comment: If the parents lie, could the UK citizen parent be excluded for having attempted to deceive the US immigration authorities?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus to be clear, the child could renounce US citizenship _before_ making significant money; once you owe tax you cannot cancel it by renouncing or expatriating. And **assets may be a bigger problem** than income; US citizens must file two different yearly reports: (1) 'foreign' (to US) bank accounts and some investments over USD10k on FBAR to FinCEN (NOT IRS) and (2) a broader set of financial assets over higher but varying thresholds (USD200k to 600k if living abroad) on form 8938 with income tax return -- and the penalties on these are quite harsh. See money.SX or IRS website.

Answer (score 10):

I'm answering this myself to summarize the discussion in comments, and because no-one else seems to have offered a clear answer.

Original question:
**Can the child enter the US on a British passport (when travelling with both parents)?**

Yes, the child can enter the USA. There are two scenarios for this happening:

1. The child enters as a British citizen, without additional questioning at the border.
2. At the border, the parents are asked if the child is a US citizen, or are asked questions to ascertain the child's eligibility for a claim to citizenship. (That is, the mother's nationality and the residence history of the mother.) Once it is ascertained that the child *is* a US citizen, the parents are given a lecture that the child should be travelling on a US passport. Since the authorities are satisfied that the child is a US citizen, the child is free to enter the US. No fine is levied.

Under scenario 2 it's unclear whether the UK passport would be stamped, or if there are any consequences for the parents if they had (knowingly or unknowingly) made a false statement on the ESTA application.

Implicit question: **Is this a good idea?**

Probably not. Particularly in the long term, several commenters noted that US citizenship carries tax obligations, and by not recognizing one's citizenship, one could fall afoul of the tax obligations and unwittingly violate some law. The parents ought to get a US passport for their child

Comment: +1. They could obviously never reject anyone *for being a citizen*. In fact, being a citizen is the only thing that *guarantees* one entry even if someone has lied. However, how do you know there won't be a fine? Or that they won't force the child to get an emergency passport then and there in the airport?

Comment: @Fiksdal: Because there is no law that provides for any fine or other penalty. They cannot "force" someone to get a passport -- the citizen can just refuse and must still be let in.

Comment: @user102008 Well, there's the law that says US citizens can not enter the US on a foreign passport

Comment: @Fiksdal: It actually says it's "unlawful", not that they cannot enter. And it is consistent with what I said.

Comment: @user102008 When you do something "unlawful" there tends to be a fine or something like that. Of course, I have no idea what would actually happen, I'm just speculating (as are you, I believe.) And we both agree that a citizen could never be refused entry.

Comment: @Fiksdal: Well I'm telling you there isn't because no law provides for a fine or other penalty.

Comment: @user102008 In that case, it seems perfectly reasonable for OP to take her baby to the US with the UK passport, which is what the OP originally wanted to do. You could go ahead and write an answer suggesting that.

Comment: @Fiksdal: That's what this answer already says.

Comment: @user102008 Yeah, but it also says that it's unclear whether there would be any consequences. I agree with that.

Comment: @Fiksdal: The statement about potential consequences is about making a false statement on the ESTA application, not for entering the US without a US passport.

Comment: @Fiksdal the law used to provide for a fine; the fine was repealed in the 1970s.  The only negative consequence is a stern talking-to, apparently.