# US citizen travelling to USA with non-US citizen child

Tags: usa, esta, children

I am dual UK-USA citizen residing in the UK. My children are UK citizens. Although technically they are eligible for USA citizenship, we've never got around to doing it (and not sure if I want to).

I'm planning a trip to the USA for later this year with my children - but without my spouse. I expect that I can apply for ESTA for the children (probability of rejection quite low) and have a notarised letter from my spouse (children's mother) stating that she does not object to me taking the children out of the country without her. The trip is for around 1-2 weeks and the purpose is to see family (my parents and other relatives).

Is there anything else I need to think of or do differently?

Comment: Are they US citizens? Do you qualify to pass it on? "A child born outside of the United States and in wedlock to a U.S. citizen parent and a non U.S. citizen parent, may acquire U.S. citizenship at birth if the U.S. citizen parent has been physically present in the United States or one of its outlying possessions for a period of five years, two of which were after the age of fourteen." https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/birth/transition-requirements/

Comment: There is no "eligible for US citizenship". You either are one or aren't one, whether or not you have registered them for it.

Comment: @BritishSam I have lived in the USA for a total of 11 years prior to the child being born.  However just under 5 of these 11 were as a US citizen.  That said, I still maintained a US residence after I moved to the UK - as the move wasn't planned to be permanent (even though it ended up being one).

Comment: Please note: I spoke with a USA immigration lawyer about children's citizenship - and was told that I don't have to worry about it now. If I want for children to travel to the USA on their UK passports, they can do so.

Comment: It's not about resident, it's physically present, you've got to prove you've been present in the US for that long. Not sure if years not as a US citizen count though. That is a good question for a different forum. If it's not counted then I don't think your children are US citizens.

Comment: @BritishSam For the purpose of this question, let's assume that they are not US citizens

Comment: @AleksG Your comment of an hour ago sounds like you've answered your own question. I think you should post it as an Answer.

Comment: @David Not quite. The question is not about passports/ESTA. Rather what else I may need to worry about besides ESTA for children and a letter from their mother.

Comment: @AleksG I took the second sentence of your comment as meaning that the consultation resulted in advice of "You can take them with you on this trip with their UK passports," which I thought was the point of your original question. Beyond having mom's letter, what else is there to do?

Comment: @AleksG: Physical presence in the US in *any* status (or no status) counts. See [8 FAM 301.7-3(B)](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030107.html#M301_7_3_B)(a)(2): "Naturalized citizens may count any time they spent in the United States or its outlying possessions both before and after being naturalized, regardless of their status.  Even citizens who, prior to lawful entry and naturalization, had spent time in the United States illegally can include that time;"

Comment: Given that it appears that the child *is* a US citizen, this question is related to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78768/us-citizen-entering-usa-as-non-citizen

Comment: @user102008 indeed it is very similar